# how to access the element inside an object

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this:

when I print  **console.log(this.myCharts)**

I am getting output like this.

```
   QueryList {dirty: false, _results: Array(0), changes: EventEmitter, length: 0, last: undefined, …}
       changes: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
       dirty: false
       first: ElementRef
           nativeElement: canvas#canvas0
           __proto__: Object
         last: ElementRef {nativeElement: canvas#canvas4}
             length: 5
              _results: (5) [ElementRef, ElementRef, ElementRef, ElementRef, ElementRef]
             __proto__: Object
```

when I print **console.log(this.myCharts['dirty'])** I getting **false** which is true, but when I do **console.log(this.myCharts['first'])** I am getting **undefined**.
how to solve this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugzhJ.png)

Comment: You forgot to add your expected example.

Comment: please add a picture of the output shown in the console, if `first` is not a property of `this.myCharts` or if the value of it is `undefined`, it will return `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

try this for example: --> **Object** is predefined and can be used to access members of an object!

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.values(object1));
```